# How do I insert an array of values into different columns of a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting values in an array like this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => English
    [1] => Arabic
)
```

I am having 2 columns in database like below.

```
lanuage1 language2
```

I want to insert the first array  [0] => English to language1 column and [1] => Arabic to language2 ,can any one suggest how can I do that? Thanks.

I tried like this:

```
$data = explode( ',', $language ) ;

print_r($data);

INSERT INTO contact(lanuage1 ,language2) VALUES ($data [0], $data [1]);
```

but its not working...

Comment: -1 what did you try so far? Show us your trials, efforts etc

Comment: Try enclosing $data[0] and $data[1] inside `'` (single quote)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$languages = array(
'0' => 'English',
'1' => 'Arabic'
);

mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO contact(lanuage1 ,language2) VALUES ('$languages[0]', '$languages[1]')");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert new record you must give every column its value , not just  language1,  language2

Maybe some columns has default values in DB, if it is,  you can skip theme in sql statment.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Or visit this page maybe help you:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you want your array values to be properly formatted, you could just use `implode()`. Consider this example:

```
$values = array('English', 'Arabic');
$statement = 'INSERT INTO contact (`language1`, `language2`) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $values) . '")';
echo $statement;
```

Sample Output:

```
INSERT INTO contact(`language1`, `language2`) VALUES ("English", "Arabic")
```

> *Important Note: You must remember that column count must have the same count as the values inside your query or else it will not work (count of columns must match the number of elements inside the array or you will have a mismatch).*

Comment: If the values are coming from a form submission, make sure to iterate over those `$values` to escape the strings before you insert them to the DB.