# Insert array values more columns to mysql in loop

Tags: mysql, arrays, simple-html-dom

I have a result generated using **SimpleHtmlDom**.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.example.com');

$count =count($html->find('table tbody tr td'))-1; //$count =170

for ($i=1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $val[$i] =$html->find('table tbody tr td',$i)->plaintext;
}
```

I don't want the first and last output, so used `$x=1 and $count-1`.

The result of output is

[image]

here, the Stock Symbol is same for every row, and there is a loop after every 8th array value.

my mysql table is ***records*** with columns "*`id,date,stock_symbol,buyer,seller,quantity,rate,amount`*"

```
"INSERT INTO records 
(id,date,stock_symbol,buyer,seller,quantity,rate,amount) 
VALUE ('$val1','$val2','$val3','$val4','$val5','$val6','$val7','$val8')",
('$val9','$val10','$val11','$val12','$val13','$val14','$val15','$val16')"
```

I could have done it manually if it was less in number, but it is more than couple of hundreds.

I tried

```
$values = array('English', 'Arabic');
$statement = 'INSERT INTO contact (`language1`, `language2`) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $values) . '")';
echo $statement;
```

from [How insert the array value one by one to MySQL table in different column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577799/how-insert-the-array-value-one-by-one-to-mysql-table-in-diffrent-column), but my array doesn't have comma (,) and didn't get any result

**EDIT: edited after the ans**

```
include('inc/simple_html_dom.php');
include('mysql.php');
// get DOM from URL or file

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.seismonepal.gov.np/index.php?action=earthquakes&show=recent');

// remove all image
foreach($html->find('div [class=block2-content] span') as $e)
$array=  str_replace(' ','',$e->plaintext);

//split all you data into the size chunks you want.
//$array = array('English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French');
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 7);

//get the amount of chunks you have.
$c = count($chunks);
$a = 0;

//then run through each chunk entering it into the database.

do{
    $values = null;
    $x = 1;

    foreach($chunks[$a] as $value) {
        $values .= "?";
        if($x < count($chunks[$a])) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }

        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO earthquake(id,date_np,local_time,lattitude,longitude,magnitude,epic_center,remarks) VALUES ({$values})";    
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);

    if(count($chunks[$a])){
        $y = 1;
        foreach($chunks[$a] as $param) {
            $query->bindValue($y, $param);
            $y++;
        }    
    }


    if($query->execute()){
        echo "Done {$a}" . "<br/>";
    }else{
        echo "Not Done {$a}" . "<br/>";
    }
    $a++;  

}while($a < $c);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make multiple querys but this is a way you could do it.

Split all you data into the size chunks you want.

```
$array = array('English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French', 'Dutch', 'English', 'French');
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 2);
```

get the amount of chunks you have.

```
$c = count($chunks);
$a = 0;
```

then run through each chunk entering it into the database.

```
do{
    $values = null;
    $x = 1;

    foreach($chunks[$a] as $value) {
        $values .= "?";
        if($x < count($chunks[$a])) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }

        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`language1`, `language2`) VALUES ({$values})";    
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);

    if(count($chunks[$a])){
        $y = 1;
        foreach($chunks[$a] as $param) {
            $query->bindValue($y, $param);
            $y++;
        }    
    }


    if($query->execute()){
        echo "Done {$a}" . "<br/>";
    }else{
        echo "Not Done {$a}" . "<br/>";
    }
    $a++;  

}while($a < $c);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** For follow up question.

You can put each of them into an array as you find them like this.

```
$array = array();

foreach($html->find('div [class=block2-content] span') as $e){
    array_push($array, $e->plaintext);
}
```

Which you can then use `array_chunk` on.

Comment: Hello Parody, Thanks for the ans, I have edited the questions and included the code, but still gives error,  array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array,

Comment: @AarveeThapa i've edited my post to include an answer to your follow up question.

Comment: Thanks again for the help.. but I am new to "prepare" function, searched over internet and tried new connection strings to mysql and database, still failed. I am getting such error, "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object". Can you please provide a little more help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got it, $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');.. thanks a lot once again